# asynchronous issue with recursive function call inside a request

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am now working on finding a document path with its name specified as an argument. In fetch_doc_path, I made two get request to get a JSON file that has an entry to all files, and then call the traverse_doc recursively to find the file path that matches the name as user input. Now the problem is, when I check the traverse_doc_obj.doc_list.length in fetch_doc_path, it always has 0 since the traverse_doc has not been finished. What can I modify the code so the checking length can execute after all recursive call finished? Namely, make both the get request and the recursion synchronous?

The minimal example is as follows, I want to check the list in traverse_doc_obj after all recursion has finished:

```
function fetch_doc_path(assistant){
    let doc_name_input = assistant.getArgument('DocName');
    ...
    get_request_handler(assistant, repo_url, function(callback){
        ...
        get_request_handler(assistant, target_repo_url, function(callback){
            traverse_doc(assistant, callback, traverse_doc_obj);
        });
    });
    // Check the list from traverse_doc_obj
}

function traverse_doc(assistant, input_callback, traverse_doc_obj){
    let input_json = JSON.parse(input_callback);
    for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(input_json['data']).length; i++){
        if (the folder has children){
            ...
            get_request_handler(assistant, sub_dir_url, function(callback){
                // call it self for traversing.
            });
        }else{
               // push path to a list in traverse_doc_obj if name matches doc_name_input
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you reduce this code to a minimal example of your problem?

Comment: Your code hurts my eyes.

Comment: edited.@lilezek

Comment: @Darkrum Sorry. Have simplified the problem.

Comment: I assume `function(callback){` should be  `function(response){` ? The way your get_request_handler works seems a bit odd.

Comment: @philraj It's a function and it makes get request inside. Callback will return the JSON body.

Comment: So you write `const body = callback()` inside the get_request_handler's callback?

Comment: I wrote callback(body); I guess the main issue is I want to make the recursive call sync, I've tested get_request_handler for this callback thing and it all works.

Comment: WillYulingLiu - @philraj's point is that normally the name "callback" is used for a function which will be called at the end of current operations. You're using the name to store the "response". It is just confusing. (Legal, but confusing.)

Comment: I see @Prisoner. Do you have any ideas on how to make it sync?

Comment: (and what does this have to do with actions-on-google?)

Comment: @Prisoner Oh because it's an assistant app code and I use firebase as host, sometimes it gets problem with timeout issue there.

Comment: Making it synchronous is not the best idea, since JavaScript is single-threaded and the UI will be frozen while waiting for your API response. Why do you need it to be sync?

Comment: Well, its a server app for starters, so a frozen UI isn't the issue. {: But I think he really just wants it to *behave* synchronously, so he can execute some code after all the data has been collected.

Comment: Ah ok, thought it was passing the directory structure back to the client side. Makes sense.

Comment: @philraj yea thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really do things synchronously when you're dealing with callbacks. I don't have a straightforward answer (because your code isn't straightforward), but I would suggest the following:

- Learn promises. If you're using Node.js version 6 and up they're built in. They're not quite synchronous, but you can treat them that way. And if you're using version 8, they're the gateway to `async/await`
- The code as you've written it needs a way to do something when all the callbacks are done. With your pattern, this is done by passing a `callback` function and calling this function as the last level in the chain.

Comment: This is great advice, and I would just add that even if you don't learn promises, if you look at how Node.js uses asynchronous functions with callbacks (pretty much everywhere) you'll notice the standard is to pass a callback function which will receive any error that occurred as the first parameter, and the result of the asynchronous operation as the second parameter. `someAsyncOperation(options, function (error, result) { ... });` Try to follow this way of writing your code for less headaches. But learning about promises (and eventually generators or async/await) will help you massively.

Comment: Thanks @Prisoner. Will take a look on the promises.